# Slow API Data Retrieval and Empty Object Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I'm working on a JavaScript project where I'm retrieving data from an API to get information about dog breeds. Specifically, I'm using The Dog API, and I have two functions for this task. However, I'm facing two different issues with these functions:

**Function 1:** **`getAllDogsData`**

```
const URL = "http://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds";
const IMAGES_URL = "https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images";
// api kei is not mandatory

const getAllDogsData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios(`${URL}?api_key=${API_KEY}`);
    const APIdata = response.data;

    const dogsAPIData = await APIdata.map(async (dogs) => {
      const imageID = dogs.reference_image_id;
      const imageUrl = await getDogImage(imageID);

      return {
        id: dogs.id,
        name: dogs.name,
        average_weight: getProm(dogs.weight.metric),
        average_height: getProm(dogs.height.metric),
        life_span: dogs.life_span,
        imageID,
        imageUrl,
      };
    });
    return dogsAPIData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error al obtener datos de perros:", error.message);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

**Issue:** When I use **`getAllDogsData`**, it returns an array of empty objects (**`[]`**). I expected it to return an array of dog data with details like name, weight, height, lifespan, and image URL. The issue seems to be related to the "reference_image_id" used to fetch the images.

**Function 2:** **`getAllDogsData2`**

```
const getAllDogsData2 = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios(`${URL}?api_key=${API_KEY}`);
    const APIdata = response.data;
    const dogsAPIData = [];

    for (const dog of APIdata) {
      const imageID = dog.reference_image_id;
      const imageUrl = await getDogImage(imageID);

      dogsAPIData.push({
        id: dog.id,
        name: dog.name,
        average_weight: getProm(dog.weight.metric),
        average_height: getProm(dog.height.metric),
        life_span: dog.life_span,
        imageID,
        imageUrl,
      });
    }

    return dogsAPIData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error al obtener datos de perros:", error.message);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

**Issue:** While **`getAllDogsData2`** does return the expected dog data, it takes a very long time to complete. I'm concerned about the performance of this function.

This funcition is used to do the fetch to the images endpoint:

```
const getDogImage = async (id) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios(`${IMAGES_URL}/${id}`);
    const responseData = response.data;
    return responseData.url;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error al obtener la imagen del perro:", error.message);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Here's how the "reference_image_id" works: The breeds endpoint returns a "reference_image_id" like "hMyT4CDXR," which I use to construct the URL for the images endpoint, like this: **`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/hMyT4CDXR`**.

The problem arises when making requests to the images endpoint using these "reference_image_id"s. In the first function if I only map the Id reference it works perfectly, but when I try to call the image function there's where all the issues appears, I suspect it has something to do with how i handle promises or asynchrony.

Can someone please help me understand what might be causing these issues, especially with fetching images, and how I can improve the performance of my code while ensuring I get the correct data from the API? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `map()` is not an async function, `await` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: You need to use `await Promise.all(APIData.map(...))`

Comment: I did remove async await from the `map()` and added `await Promise.all()`. even though it does't return an array of empy objects anymore, now the imageUrl property does return an emty object, wich makes me think the problem is in the image function

Comment: Add `console.log(responseData)` to `getDogImage()`

Comment: It works as espected, returns the image url, it leaves me without ideas